# Webhook received, but Derivative Properties JSON cannot be downloaded

Tags: autodesk-forge

I used the Model Derivative API to convert the IFC file.
In order to use Derivative Properties JSON, I registered to receive notification of the completion of the conversion via webhook.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/extraction.finished/

However, when I requested the API to download the Derivative Properties JSON immediately after receiving the notification of conversion completion, I could not retrieve the data.
By requesting the API after some time, the data will be retrieved, but the webhook cannot be used as a trigger.

Is there a webhook that will notify me when Derivative Properties JSON will be available?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is as designed. webhook of extract complete only notifies when the translation is completed. While the metadata/properties endpoint will prepare the response json on-demand, so it takes time for the backend engine completes. There is not yet webhook that can tell when  this is ready.  With the enhancement of properties search of  Model Derivative, the response would be quick than before

Comment: . On AU class Forge road map, our leads talked about this feature https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Forge-Road-Map-2021#video. Please watch our update about the enhancement in the future.